# HTC Droid Incredible cannot load text message

Tags: sms, htc-droid-incredible

My phone, HTC Droid Incredible, was working perfectly fine. Then it just stopped letting me open up my text message threads. All it does is say loading and I left it for about 10 minutes and still nothing.

Everything else on my phone works. I've restarted it four times and it's still not working.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You could try backing up your messages with something like [SMS Backup & Restore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.riteshsahu.SMSBackupRestore) and then wiping the Messaging apps data and cache.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar symptom once and it was caused by the SIM card coming loose, so try this: turn the phone off completely, eject the SIM card, replace the SIM card, and turn the phone back on again.